# What is the value of the variables in the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> $$x_1 + y_1 = 3$$
>   $$y_1 - x_3 = -1$$
>   $$x_3 + y_3 = 7$$
>   $$x_1 - y_3 = -3$$
>
> Find the values of $x_1$, $x_3$, $y_1$ and $y_3$.

All I am getting is $x_1 + x_3 = 4$ and $y_1 + y_3 = 6$.

Comment: This system has infinitely many solutions of the form, $x_1=a$, $x_3=4-a$, $y_1 = 3-a$ and $y_2 = a+3$ for any $a\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1=a$, $y_1=b$, $x_3=c$ and $y_3=d$.

Thus, $b=3-a$ and from the second we obtain $c=4-a$, which from the third gives $d=3+a$ and we see that the fourth holds.

Id est, got infinitely many solutions:
$$\{(a,3-a,4-a,3+a)\}$$

Answer (score 1):

With this sort of system one should note that it can be represented as a matrix, where the elements are the coefficients for each variable:
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 7\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -3\end{array} \right]$$

Of course, to find a solution (if one exists), one must change the matrix $M$ into reduced row-echelon form, denoted here as $M_{rrf}$, which is as follows:
$$M_{rrf} = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 6\end{array} \right] \\ \text{this was carried out by the following $\it row$ operations:} \\ 
 -R_1 + R_4 \to R_4 \\ R_2 + R_3 \to R_3 \\R_4 + R_3 \to R_3 \\ -R_4 \to R_4 \\ -R_3 + R_2 \to R_2 \\ -R_3 + R_1 \to R_1 \\ -R_2 \to R_2 \\$$

Thus, since the 3rd row of $M_{rrf}$ is $\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$, we have that $\text{dim kerM} = 1$ (recall that the dimension of the kernel is defined as the nullity, $\text{null M}$ of the matrix). Since, $null(M) = 1$, the system has *infinitely many* solutions.

Now, as shown by Michael's answer, we can *parametrize* our solution to create an expression that generates *all* of the solutions. Begin by defining the following: $$x_1 = 3 = a \\ x_3 = 1 = b \\ y_1 = 0 = c \\ y_3 = 6 = d$$ which gives us $$ a = a
 \\ a + c = 3 \\ -b + c = -1 \\ a - d = -3 \\ \text{which simplifies to:} \\ a = a \\ b = c + 1 = 4 - a \\ c = 3 - a \\ d = a + 3 $$

Therefore, the solution set for the system is $ \{a, 4-a, 3-a, 3+a \}$